# Does anybody know how to make a constraint that ensures there is a certain character in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I need a constraint where @ must be included in the email address. Any ideas? Using Oracle Live SQL if that helps.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_email
    check (email like '%@%');
```

Note:  Full "format" validation of emails addresses is much more complicated -- and requires regular expressions.  If you do some searching, you can probably find some already-built regular expressions for better validation.

Comment: If that's so, @augi11, why don't you accept / upvote the answer?

Comment: @Littlefoot I did upvote the answer. I'm new to this site so I guess I need more rep. That's why I commented my thanks. If I get more rep I'll come back and upvote it :)

Comment: Yes, you need at least 15 reputation points to be able to vote. But, you can **accept** the answer (which will reward you with 2 points).

Comment: @Littlefoot I can't see an option for that. Where is it? Go easy on the noob lol...

Comment: Okay I've found it my bad, thanks again Gordon!